# Existential deposit in EVM compatible address

Tags: evm, frontier, existential-deposit

I understand that there is an existential deposit for native token. But, there is any existential deposit for EVM compatible address H160?

Comment: Existential Deposit is a part of the `Balances` pallet, and not related to the Address format. Are you asking if there is Existential Deposit in a Substrate chain that uses [Frontier](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is up to each individual chain to decide.

By default, EVM uses pallet-balances to handle native token, so the same ED rule applies.

It is possible to configure the pallets to use other pallets to handle native token of EVM or simply configure the ED to zero.